# Prove that $n<2^n$ for any natural number $n$.

Tags: proof-writing

How do I prove that $n<2^n$ for any natural number $n$, assuming basic facts about the algebra of exponents?

Comment: Try induction on $n$.

Comment: Duplicate of above

Comment: You can probably just use Cantor's theorem which says that any set's power set has larger carnality then it does. If a set $S$ has $k$ elements ($|S|=k$) then $|\mathscr P(S)|=2^k$ ($\mathscr P(x)$ is the powerset of $x$). So as long as you can show that $|\mathscr P(S)| = 2^{|S|}$ you should be good.

Comment: @BenjiAltman This is hilariously overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof is by induction on $n$. For the base case consider when $n = 1$ so we get $1 < 2^{1}$ which is true. Now suppose the property that $n < 2^{n}$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then for some integer $k = n + 1$ we get

\begin{align*}
k &< 2^{k}\\
n + 1  &< 2^{n + 1}\\
n + 1 &< 2^{n} + 2^{n}\\
1 &< 2^{n}
\end{align*}
Which is true by the induction hypothesis.